# Scroll background until the entire background image has been shown

Tags: html, css, background, scroll

I have a very tall image that I'm using as a background for the body tag. However, the page may be longer than this image, so after a while I see the background color since I use `no-repeat` (the background is not a pattern).

Is there a way to keep the background scrollable, and then when I reach the end of the image, keep it "stuck" to the bottom, although the page keeps scrolling?

Comment: You may find help by searching "parallax scrolling" (if I'm understanding you correctly). In any case, it can't be done with CSS only.

Comment: @dwreck08 at the moment my code is 
`body {
    background: url(../images/elefanti_bkg.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;`
but the result is obviously different!

Comment: `background-position: fixed` don't do?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown That wouldn't scroll the background *at all*. The idea is to scroll the bg image until it reaches the bottom of that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use an extra fixed layer with the bottom of the picture setted to transparent, and then listen to the scroll event to detect when you reach the bottom of the original background, set the fixed layer visible and voila, you have it! If you need help in any of these, please provide a snippet of your code so I can implement in it for you.

Comment: instead of adding another layer, I'd just alternate  `background-attachment: fixed / scroll;` on the body element.

Comment: Not a bad idea either, but my experience is that big images as scrollable background can cause lagging. So since the Q pointed out the usage of a "very tall image" I would go with the layer in this particular case to avoid performance issues. Otherwise I agree that that would be the proper solution.